# how to save HTML values in Js

Tags: javascript, html

here's the html code :

```
<p id="Message" value="This is the home message">Computers are fast !</p>"
```

I want to store the message part (Computers are fast !) in a Javascript variable using .getAttribute

What should I add in .getAttribute('')?

```
let message = document.querySelector('#Message').getAttribute('');
let internal = document.querySelector('#Message').getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, and must be fixed before proceeding. `value` is not a valid attribute name on `p` elements. If you want to invent your own attribute names, these **must** be prefixed with `data-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. It isn't an attribute. The text content of an element is found in [the `textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: Hi @TLS, If this is the most suitable answer, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027611) the answer by clicking the check mark :D

Answer (score -1):

It's an `InnerHTML`

```
let message = document.querySelector('#Message').innerHTML;
```